# Display Local Storage Data on Page

Tags: javascript

I know there is a similar post about displaying local storage data, but my structure wasn't quite like it and I wasn't able to figure out how could I do it. So here it goes.

P.S: There might be some syntax/logical mistakes regarding the ES6 (I'm still trying to get used to it)

So here is my JS File:

```
const list = document.getElementById("list");
const input = document.getElementById("new-todo");
let toDoList = [];
let toDoObj = {
    toDoName: String,
    toDoDone: Boolean,
    toDoID: 0,
}



input.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        addToDo(input.value, toDoObj);
        updateLocalStorage();
    }
});

list.addEventListener("click", e => {
    ulComp = e.target;
    if(ulComp.id === "dltBtn") {
        removeToDo(ulComp, toDoList);
        updateLocalStorage();
    }
    else if (ulComp.classList.contains("todo-text")) {
        doneToDo(ulComp, toDoList);
        updateLocalStorage();
    }
});


const addToDo = (newToDo, obj) => {
    if(input.value) {
        const toDoItem = `<li id="item"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" data-text="${newToDo}" id="dltBtn"></i><span data-text="${newToDo}" class="todo-text">${newToDo}</span> </li>`;
        list.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", toDoItem );
        obj = {
            toDoName: newToDo,
            toDoDone: false,
            toDoID: toDoObj.toDoID++
        };
        toDoList.push(obj);
        input.value = "";
    }
    else {
        alert("Please Type In A To-Do!");
    }
}
const doneToDo = (item, list) => {
    item.classList.toggle("done");
    for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].toDoName === item.getAttribute("data-text") && item.classList.contains("done")) {
            list[i].toDoDone = true;
        }
        else if (list[i].toDoName === item.getAttribute("data-text")) {
            list[i].toDoDone = false;
        }
    }
}

const removeToDo = (item, list) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length;i++) {  
        if (list[i].toDoName === item.getAttribute("data-text")) {
            item.parentElement.remove();
            list.splice(i,1);
            console.log(list);
        }
    }
}

const updateLocalStorage = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("TODOs", JSON.stringify(toDoList));
}

const loadLocalStorage = () => {
    JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('TODOs'));
}
```

So far I was able to update the data on certain actions and getting it back on refresh. But I couldn't figure out how to display it.

I've tried passing `JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('TODOs'));` attributes and values into the variable and call the `addToDo()` function, but since it's taking `input.value` and `toDoObj` arguements, I couldn't get it working.

Basically, (if I have no other mistakes in my logic) I want to be able to show the items on my locally stored array on the page when the page is refreshed.

Any help is very much appreciated

P.S 2: I'm still a newbie, so I'm sorry the code is messy and if there are some logical mistakes. ( feedback on those are appreciated as well.

Thanks!

Snippet:

```js
const list = document.getElementById("list");
const input = document.getElementById("new-todo");
let toDoList = [];
let toDoObj = {
    toDoName: String,
    toDoDone: Boolean,
    toDoID: 0,
}



input.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        addToDo(input.value, toDoObj);
        updateLocalStorage();
    }
});

list.addEventListener("click", e => {
    ulComp = e.target;
    if(ulComp.id === "dltBtn") {
        removeToDo(ulComp, toDoList);
        updateLocalStorage();
    }
    else if (ulComp.classList.contains("todo-text")) {
        doneToDo(ulComp, toDoList);
        updateLocalStorage();
    }
});


const addToDo = (newToDo, obj) => {
    if(input.value) {
        const toDoItem = `<li id="item"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" data-text="${newToDo}" id="dltBtn"></i><span data-text="${newToDo}" class="todo-text">${newToDo}</span> </li>`;
        list.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", toDoItem );
        obj = {
            toDoName: newToDo,
            toDoDone: false,
            toDoID: toDoObj.toDoID++
        };
        toDoList.push(obj);
        input.value = "";
    }
    else {
        alert("Please Type In A To-Do!");
    }
}
const doneToDo = (item, list) => {
    item.classList.toggle("done");
    for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].toDoName === item.getAttribute("data-text") && item.classList.contains("done")) {
            list[i].toDoDone = true;
        }
        else if (list[i].toDoName === item.getAttribute("data-text")) {
            list[i].toDoDone = false;
        }
    }
}

const removeToDo = (item, list) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length;i++) {  
        if (list[i].toDoName === item.getAttribute("data-text")) {
            item.parentElement.remove();
            list.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}

const updateLocalStorage = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("TODOs", JSON.stringify(toDoList));
}

const loadLocalStorage = () => {
    JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('TODOs'));
}
```

```css
.done {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>To Do List</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <!-- FONT AWESOME -->
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b9a2aee93e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>To Do List</h1>
                <input id="new-todo" type="text" name="todo">
                <ul id="list">

                </ul>
        </div>
            
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please post your html or working demo, so we can check it where is the issue

Comment: My bad. I added a snippet before posting but forgot about it on the next edit. Adding now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to call `addToDo()` for all the items in the retrieved array. You can do something like this.

```
    const items = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('TODOs'));
    items.forEach((item) => {
        addTodo(item)
    });
```

Comment: in your `addToDo()` function check for `if(newToDo)` instead of `if(input.value)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the suggestion. Where should I call the function `loadLocalStorage()` function? When I do it on the global scope, I can't access before initialization error And If I call it after I define it, I got not defined error for my other functions. Sorry I'm fairly new to localstorage. Actually this is my first time using it.

Comment: Was able to make it work. See my answer for full functionality.
This answer was the correct one in terms of logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
const localStorageLoad = () => {
    const items = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('TODOs'));
    items.forEach( (item) => {
        addToDo(item.toDoName, item);
    });
}
```

Editing `localStorageLoad` function as above and calling the function on window load as below, made everything work perfectly.

```
window.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
    localStorageLoad();
});
```

So Checking Aditya's answer. It was mostly the correct answer in terms of logic.